# Create Task automatically when Pull request is created in Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

My project is hosted in Bitbucket and version controlled through Git. Is there a way to automatically create tasks when a PR is created? I have heard of Bot integrations with BitBucket but couldn't find much about this on the internet. Is this possible? I would appreciate some guidance on how this can be achieved.

P.S: The tasks I would want to create are the same with every PR - mainly like a checklist that ensures commits are squashed, its been unit tested and so on..

Comment: Create tasks _where_, in some other system? The first result in a web search for "Bot integrations with BitBucket" (your exact words) is https://bitbucket.org/integrations/cloud - is the tool you want to integrate listed there?

Comment: Create Tasks in Bitbucket

Comment: along these lines https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66617391/automatically-add-tasks-to-new-btibucket-pull-request

Comment: Haven't use the linked one below. But you may check this since it is for the same purpose. 
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1225571/pull-request-checklist-buddy-for-bitbucket?tab=overview&hosting=cloud